# how can I get my user icon on the side nav bar to the center? and how can i create border for the side nav bar?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to get the user profile icon to be centered so i'm having the hardest time doing it. I also tried adding border around the nav bar so it wont show on my page and i cant figure it out. I'm trying to recreate what Uber has- see pic attached.[image: uber rider side nav bar] Would someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

//FROM MY HTML PAGE

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            <!-- side bar -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="profile-sidenav-cell">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user custom-icon"></span>   
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="profile-sidenav-cell">
                <ul class="side-menu-tabs">
                  <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
            <!-- side bar end -->
          </div>


          <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color: green;">Page Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

//FROM MY CSS PAGE

```
.profile-sidenav-cell{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.profile-sidenav-div {
  background-color: purple; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.custom-icon {
  font-size: 70px;
  background: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:0.5px solid #ccc; 
  color:#ccc; 
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.profile-sidenav-cell ul {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.profile-sidenav-cell ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray; 
    padding: 11px 11px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    display:block;
}

.profile-sidenav-cell ul li a:visited {
    color: gray;
}

.profile-sidenav-cell ul li a:hover, .side-menu-tabs ul li .current {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: may be to add 'display:flex;justify-content: center' to   .profile-sidenav-cell  class will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this css classes

```
.custom-icon {
  font-size: 70px;
  background: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:0.5px solid #ccc; 
  color:#ccc; 
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);

}
.profile-sidenav-cell ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray; 
    padding: 11px 11px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

And html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            <!-- side bar -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="profile-sidenav-cell">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user custom-icon"></span>   
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="profile-sidenav-cell">
                <ul class="side-menu-tabs">
                  <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
            <!-- side bar end -->
          </div>


          <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color: green;">Page Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/64ccmL0o/3/

Comment: this was really helpful. thanks for your help again!